# Zener diode - Zener voltage vs reverse voltage specification

Tags: zener, diode-clamp, reverse-breakdown

This may be a very simple question with a straight-forward answer, but I cannot get a clear answer on this.

Consider the following [Zener diode](https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/Products/3SMAJ5913B%7E3SMAJ5943B(DO-214AC).pdf). The table on page 2 lists a column for **Zener voltage** \$V_Z\$ and also a column for **Reverse voltage** \$V_R\$, with \$V_R\$ < \$V_Z\$ for all the device variants.

What is the difference between these two parameters? If I want to use the Zener diode to clamp the maximum input voltage to a circuit to 24 V (in case of a transient*), do I choose the device based on \$V_Z\$ = 24 V or \$V_R\$ = 24 V?

*NOTE * - This will actually form part of a circuit where a TVS diode is used, but I cannot find a TVS diode that will clamp at a maximum of 24 V with a maximum working voltage of about 19 V (the actual operating voltage is 12-18 V). I am therefore resorting to choosing a TVS with a maximum clamping voltage higher than 24 V and want to use the Zener (placed in parallel, after the TVS) to clamp the input voltage to 24 V in case of a transient.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: TVS diodes are Zener diodes.

---

You should pick Vz = 24 V

Pick part number: 3SMAJ5934B

---

Vr is the latest voltage at which the diode is not yet entered the Zener region and draws a small current called "maximum reverse current".

3SMAJ5934B maximum reverse current is 1 μA

Once entered the Zener region the diode will draw much more current than 1 μA. See the test data in the following table.

[image]

Comment: *Once entered the Zener region the diode will draw 15.6 mA* Not really, when a **test current** of 15.6 mA is applied to the device, a zener voltage \$V_Z\$ of typically 24 V will develop across the diode. Generally "test" currents and voltages are **applied to the device** rather than that this value is measured. The test current is a **test condition**.

Comment: Thanks Enrico and Bimpelrekkie for your answer and comment.